# Drupal 8 image with token not shown in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, token, drupal-8

I'm quite confused of this: I have fresh installation of Drupal 8.0.3. In FF (44.0.2) if I add an immage to the default article content type, it's not being displayed (just the alt text).

But it works fine in IE11, Edge and latest Chrome.

I have found that problem is in token beind added by Drupal. Original attribute is:

```
 src="/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/night.jpg?itok=n5nRzlH-"
```

if I change it (in Firebug for example) to:

```
src="/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/night.jpg"
```

the picture is shown properly. Also change to

```
src="http://domain.com//sites/default/files/styles/large/public/night.jpg?itok=n5nRzlH-"
```

makes it working.

Any idea how to handle this? I have even no idea if the problem is in FF or Drupal or somewhere else :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK - just after posting this question I've figured out how to solve it - not sure if caused by any extensions or FF settings but after FF reset (can be done via Help -> Restart with disabled addons -> Chose FF reset in following dialogue) image is shown.

Comment: i had a problem with firefox (44.0.2) and drupal and i solved with reset of firefox. So i think that in both cases was a problem with FF

Comment: I'm facing the same issue tried with your solution but not working. And also the image is not coming in chrome as well